# Render node author profile image in node template

Tags: theming, 8

I am working on customization Node template file in Drupal 8, I added another field to user in `admin/config/people/accounts/fields` ( my field is **field_bio**). Now I want to render author image( with specified image style) and **field_bio** in node template`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Good question, I found this [How do I print/display an image in Drupal 8, using an image style I've cretaed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33510051/how-do-i-print-display-an-image-in-drupal-8-using-an-image-style-ive-created) so give the accepted answer a try or the comment below it, let me know if it works.

Comment: @NoSssweat hi, ok, I am waiting for your answer. ( I couldn't wait very much, I did it with `    if(isset($vars['node']) && $vars['node']->getType()=='blog'){
    $author = $vars['node']->get('uid')->entity;
        $vars['author'] = array(
        'bio' => isset($author->field_user_bio->value)?$author->field_user_bio->value:NULL,
         'img_uri' => isset($author->user_picture->entity->uri->value)?$author->user_picture->entity->uri->value:NULL,
        'full_name' => isset($author->field_full_name->value)?$author->field_full_name->value:NULL,
        );
   }` ,do u have better solu.?

Comment: you didn't try using Twig template?

Comment: @NoSssweat I pas them as variables and in twig template I using them( because I didn't find another solution ) , if you have a solution please post it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you like to do this in ui with one line of code:

1) add a view mode for user and name it "nodeview":

> /admin/structure/display-modes/view/add/user

2) activate the new view mode "nodeview" at the bottom of this page in "Custom Display Settings", then you get a new tab for the view mode "nodeview". Configure which fields are displayed and how they are formatted:

> /admin/config/people/accounts/display

3) Use the new view mode to render the author of the node in node preprocess:

```
$variables['author'] = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getViewBuilder('user')->view($variables['node']->getOwner(), 'nodeview');
```

4) Put the variable in twig

```
{{ author }}
```

This method allows full customization in ui and it is fast, because the rendered author gets cached and will be reused in every node referenced.

Comment: It can be helpful to add a template suggestion for the view mode using [hook_theme_suggestions_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_theme_suggestions_alter/8.3.x)

Comment: This works like a charm!